# How to add structured data to each gutenberg block like images,video,paragraph,table

Tags: wordpress, schema.org, structured-data, json-ld, yoast

Infact i need to specify my structured data for content blocks like Images ,Videos,Paragraph in a page and i should be able to see those inside script type="application/ld+json" class="yoast-schema-graph
 for my wordpress site.I use Wordpress Gutenberg editor In Worpress Version 5.4.1 with Yoast SEO.

Comment: It seems like Yoast [has an option for Video structured data](https://developer.yoast.com/features/schema/plugins/video-seo/). What specific kind of structured data are you trying to add to your images and paragraphs?

Comment: Yes Checked on the Video SEO plugin which is not what i wanted.Is there any easy way from gutenberg dashboard itself to achieve it without an additional SEO Plugin or a code editing in functions.php.
I need to add "@type":"ImageObject" and "@id" structured data to each Image block, my webpage through Gutenberg editor.Similarly "@type":"article" and "@id" for paragraphs .

Comment: Basically **i wanted to add structured data to every block  in my webpage through Gutenberg and YOAST SEO.Is that Possible ?**